# Filtering an ng-repeat on multiple specific values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter an ng-repeat with 2 of the data's columns.

**Data**

- name (string)
- address = [{city (string)}] (array)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="search-query" ng-model="search.attributes.name" />
<select ui-select2 id="select2" data-placeholder="Type" ng-model="search.attributes.address.0.city" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
</select>

<tr ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:search | limitTo: 10">
```

For some reason, none of the data show up at all in this case. Although when I delete the `select` box entirely, then it all populates, but when I type something in the search box, nothing shows (as if the filter filtered out everything.)

Comment: Can you output `search` object, how does it look?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed as if search.attributes.name wasn't initiated as `''` but as `undefined`. So the filter didn't default to allowing *anything* but defaulted with only allowing things `undefined` through, which was none.

So the answer was to add this to my controller:

```
$scope.search = {};
$scope.attributes.name = '';
$scope.attributes.address.0.city = '';
```

Comment: I would suggest that you use `<select ng-options="...">` instead of doing your manual `ng-repeat`.  It not only makes your code cleaner but does a lot of what you're trying to do automatically.  You can see the docs for that [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:select).